# Is there a way to prevent marker flicker when region change?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have problem on my mapview, happens when the `onRegionChange` fire the marker looks flicker or blinking. I don't know the reason why this happen in the mapview.

Mapview Code:

```
<MapView
            initialRegion={{
                latitude: currentCoordinate[0],
                longitude: currentCoordinate[1],
                latitudeDelta: latitudeDelta,
                longitudeDelta: longitudeDelta,
            }}
            onRegionChange={(e) => handlerUpdateAddressInfo(e)}
            ref={mapRef}
            style={styles.map}
            provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
            showsUserLocation={true}
            mapType="standard"
            loadingEnabled={false}
            showsMyLocationButton={true}
            showsBuildings={false}
            minZoomLevel={13}
            followsUserLocation
            maxZoomLevel={18}
            tracksViewChanges={false}
            onMapReady={() => {mapRef.current.fitToSuppliedMarkers(['mk1'],{ edgePadding: 
            {top: 20,
                right:20,
                bottom: 20,
                left:20}
        
            })}}
        >
            <Marker
                coordinate={{
                    latitude: currentCoordinate[0],
                    longitude: currentCoordinate[1],
                }}
                key={`project-${type}-${new Date().getMilliseconds()}`}
                pinColor={'#0c43b0'}
                identifier={'mk1'}
            >
                <Image alt={'project_logo'} source={require('../../../assets/pin.png')} w="38" h="51" />
            </Marker>

        </MapView>
```

Handler Function:

```
const handlerUpdateAddressInfo = useCallback((e) => {
    console.log(e)
    setCurrentCoordinate([e?.latitude, e?.longitude])
}, []);
```

State:

```
const [currentCoordinate, setCurrentCoordinate] = useState([coordinate[0], coordinate[1]])
```

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by flickering, can you provide a video?
As ```handlerUpdateAddressInfo``` has an empty dependency array it should get called only once.

Comment: Why are you updating the marker every time the region changes?